# Rename worksheet to cell value keeping format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below code works.  It will rename my worksheet to a cell's value.  But in the case of a new project, the cell's value happens to be a date 8/4/2012 for example.  If i run the below code, the sheet gets renamed to "Sat Aug 04 2012 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)".

How can i adjust the below code so the sheet's name reflects only "8/4/2012"

```
  // The code below will rename the active sheet to last production week's date
var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("P1").getValue();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities?hl=fr-FR#formatDate) to get the format you want.

in your code it should be

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(Utilities.formatDate(myValue, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

if you're not in GMT don't forget to change that since even if you don't use hours it will mess up your dates sometimes ;-)

Comment: I know i want the format to be formatDate("mm/dd/yyyy") but i have no idea where to put that in my code above.  I am not familiar with this coding at all.

Comment: sorry, I could have been more descriptive, I edited my answer, hoping this will work for you.