# Create template Google Sheet with script to rename from cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a Google Sheet template where a user can enter a value (Project URN) in a cell and run a script to save the template as a sheet, renamed with the Project URN.

I have created a test Google Sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IPpQyYHl_TtNa1lGpmu4dlzwTFjOotV2OcnxFT84iUk/edit?usp=sharing

This sheet has the following script, but I cant get the renaming function to correctly work.

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B7RrbZuJGLlha3NvM3ZqcTY3MDA"); 

  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId())
    .(makeCopy(values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(2, 2).getValues()), destFolder);
} //END function saveAsSpreadsheet
```

I did also find the following article but wasn't able to turn it to my use. However, the secret must be here somewhere! [Rename worksheet to cell value keeping format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804116/rename-worksheet-to-cell-value-keeping-format)

Kitten

Comment: There should not be a parenthesis before makeCopy.  You have `(makeCopy`  You should break up that long chain by adding some variables.  That is better for debugging.  If you want to chain everything together later, then you can always do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it. Please try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get spreadsheet
  var id = ss.getId(); // Get spreadsheet ID
  var sstocopy = DriveApp.getFileById(id); //Get spreadsheet with DriveApp
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // Grab the sheet in order to find the name of the new spreadsheet to be created
  var sheet_name = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue(); // Get the value, in this case: Project Urn
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXX"); // Get the folder where the sheet needs to be placed.
  sstocopy.makeCopy(sheet_name,folder); // Make the copy of the sheet in that folder.
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.